# Proving $\{0^{2^n}\}$ is not regular using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am currently learning the pumping lemma, and encountered the following question, which I am unable to solve:

> Prove that $L = \{ 0^n \mid \text{$n$ is power of 2}\}$ is not regular.

I considered $w = 0^{2^n}$, where $n$ is the pumping lemma constant. Then I divided $w$ into $xyz$, where $y \ne \epsilon$ and $|xy| \leq n$. Hence, $|y|$ will be between 1 and $n$. So, $|xy^kz|$ satisfies $L$ if $|y| = 2$ for all values of $k$ and it is within the bound. So, how is $L$ irregular?

The question is to prove it is irregular but here it is coming as regular.

Comment: The pumping lemma requires $xy^kz$ to be in the language for *all values* of $k$, not just for some value.

Comment: @rici so, if |y| = 2, all values of k will be valid

Comment: All multiples of 2 are not powers of 2.

Comment: Though it's not the case here, some irregular languages satisfy the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $k = 2$ then, writing $|y| = m$, we get
$$ xy^2z = 0^{2^n+m}. $$
Since $1 \leq m \leq n$, we have
$$ 2^n < 2^n+m \leq 2^n+n. $$
Cantor's theorem shows that $n < 2^n$, and in particular,
$$ 2^n < 2^n+m < 2^{n+1}. $$
Therefore $xy^2z \notin L$.

---

Let me take this opportunity to mention another misconception. *There are some non-regular languages which satisfy the pumping lemma.* Therefore the fact that you couldn't prove that a certain language is non-regular using the pumping lemma *does not imply* that the language is regular.